# User Profile Synchronisation to Multiple Domains

Tags: user-profile, claims-based-auth, profile-sync

I cannot find a definitive trusted resource that specifies whether or not the FIMS service can sync with multiple domains. Has anyone got any good information on this?

Also if we sync to an AD source which contains stubs of users, but have a web application in which they are actually authenticating against a custom membership/role provider, will the profiles returned be available to the users given that they will have logged in using claims based authentication?

On top of all this we are using BCS to the same custom membership store to augment the profiles.

Help and references are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm understanding you properly.  If you're talking about the User Profile Sync, yes, you can have it import profiles from multiple AD domains -- we use two at work.

If you're talking about fusing profile from AD with membership and roles from a custom provider, good luck.

Comment: Dan, can you let me know the way in which you have setup multiple AD to sync with SharePoint? I have a scenario wherein we have multiple ADs (in different domains) and we have to sync users with a single SharePoint application.